# openWRT in UBNT Unifi LR unstable ping

Tags: networking, ping, wireless-access-point, openwrt

I installed openwrt in UBNT Unifi LR.
Here's the config:

```
config interface 'VLAN10'
option type 'bridge'
option ifname 'eth0.10'

config interface 'VLAN8'
option ifname 'eth0.8'
option proto 'static'
option ipaddr '192.168.101.24'
option netmask '255.255.255.0'
option gateway '192.168.101.1'
option dns '192.168.101.1'
```

wireless is bridged to VLAN10, VLAN8 for management.
I already disable the firewall and the dnsmasq from startup.

I can connect to the AP and I don't experience any lagging in browsing or download when using the AP, but if I ping from my router (which has vlan8 interface), the ping is not stable, it said: "Destination Host Unreachable".
When I can ping, and login to the AP, I checked that the AP is not busy, low bandwidth and low CPU usage.

I didn't experience this problem with other hardware (openwrt/ddwrt based), so I think this is not network issue.

What is happening? 
How can I fix this?

Comment: I think the problem is the VLAN Tag, I have several Access Points that mostly seen down by the router, but in reality they were not. I have DLINK AP, if I put AP management ip address under VLAN Tag, the AP mostly seen as down, but if I put the management IP address without VLAN, everything is fine.